# Get the list of downloaded YouTube offline video's title from another device

Tags: youtube

Is there a way wherein I can see what YouTube videos I have saved offline on my phone on another device with the same Google account?

Is there a way to see a list of my saved YouTube videos?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way wherein I can see what YouTube videos I have saved
>   offline on my phone on another device with the same Google account?

AFAIK the answer is No, and below is brief theory explaining why so.

When YouTube Download those videos for offline viewing, it basically store those videos on THAT device's internal storage. The location for those videos is something similar to below path.

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

There might be a minor change to this location or path on other Android devices, but all those downloaded files are saved as .exo files, in an **Internal Storage of a device**!

Those "offline" videos can only be played using official YouTube App, and those videos simply can not be played using any other Video/Media player application.

YouTube (means Google) controls the access to the offline file.

The permission is controlled on their server to access those downloaded files and Since they are part of specific device, you cannot access/view those using Google Account, from another device.

> Is there a way to see a list of my saved YouTube videos?

Yes, you can see the list of all offline saved videos on same device by 2 ways

1. As mentioned earlier, using the path from Internal store.
2. Through YouTube App itself. Open YouTube App, click on the right most icon(which looks like person/contact). Here you can see "**Available Offline**" section with **Saved videos**, click it to see all offline saved videos on your device

Comment: Is there a way that a list of offline videos can be exported?

Comment: @siliconpi i am not aware of such feature. to the best of my understanding, offline videos are there to be viewed only via YouTube app and there is no easy way to access them by any other method.

Answer (score 0):

very great question and here is some answers from my side and you can use the screenshot option with long screenshot to capture all that list in a picture format.
with this information collected in screenshots you can use or download videos on your other mobile as you asking for the help.